# Terraform / Cloudformation - Pass parameter as YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I use Terraform to launch a Cloudformation stack to create Glue Databrew resources that don't exist yet on Terraform.

The thing is that I've a variable in Terraform that corresponds to the list of my data sources and in order to create the databrew resources associated to this data, I loop over my list to create one instance of my Cloudformation template for each data source.

Inside this template, I've a resource that I want to be different per data source. It correspond to the AWS::DataBrew::Ruleset resource.

It looks like this :

```
DataBrewDataQualityRuleset:
Type: AWS::DataBrew::Ruleset
Properties:
  Name: !Ref RuleSetName
  Description: Data Quality ruleset
  Rules:
    - Name: Check columns for missing values
      Disabled: false
      CheckExpression: AGG(MISSING_VALUES_PERCENTAGE) == :val1
      SubstitutionMap:
        - ValueReference: ":val1"
          Value: '0'
      ColumnSelectors:
        - Regex: ".*"
    - Name: Check two
      Disabled: false
      CheckExpression: :col IN :list
      SubstitutionMap:
        - ValueReference: ":col"
          Value: "`group`"
        - ValueReference: ":list"
          Value: "[\"Value1\", \"Value2\"]"
  TargetArn: !Sub SomeArn
```

What I want to do is, extract the Rules part of the component and create one file where I will put all my rules per data sources. In fact having something like below :

```
DataBrewDataQualityRuleset:
Type: AWS::DataBrew::Ruleset
Properties:
  Name: !Ref RuleSetName
  Description: Data Quality ruleset
  Rules: !Ref Rules
  TargetArn: !Sub SomeArn
```

And in my terraform, my Rules parameter would be my actual set of rules for one particular data source.

I've thought about having one YAML file from which I would loop on terraform but I'm not sure it's doable and if cloudformation would accept YAML as parameter type.

Below you'll also find my terraform component :

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "databrew_jobs" {
  for_each = var.data_sources
  name          = "datachecks-${each.value.stack_name}"
  parameters = {
    Bucket = "test_bucket"
    DataSetKey = "raw/${each.value.job_name}"
    DataSetName = "dataset-${each.value.stack_name}"
    RuleSetName = "ruleset-${each.value.stack_name}"
    JobName = "profile-job-${each.value.stack_name}"
    DataSourceName = "${each.value.stack_name}"
    JobResultKey = "databrew-results/${each.value.job_name}"
    RoleArn = iam_role_test.arn
  }
  template_body = file("${path.module}/databrew-job.yaml")
}
```

Do you have any idea how could I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you looking for this maybe: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/databrew_ruleset?

Comment: Wow thanks...didn't even know it existed !

Comment: Yeah, it is a kind of compromise between CloudFormation and Terraform. :) But anyway, I think this could be done even the way you want, I'm just unsure where you want those parameters and you could use the `templatefile` built-in function to make some changes in the `databrew-job.yml` file. If you post that file as well, I might find a workaround.

Comment: In fact, I'd rather use the terraform components because I was having my cloudformation stack only to create my databrew ressources. Thanks for your help !
If I don't manage to get it work as wanted, I'll reopen this thread ;) thanks again !

Comment: @MarkoE : It seems like awscc is a bit unstable. I managed to get it work but very unstable especially when destroying/recreating rules. What would be a workaround with the initial solution using Cloudformation please ? The databrew-job.yml consist of only 3 resources, a databrew job, dataset, and Ruleset.

Comment: Ok, but where do you want to add those values you mention? In that databrew job YML file or somewhere else?

Comment: I guess in my terraform template which will replace the rules inside my cloudformation template.
To be simple, I have multiple data sources and I want to create one data quality pipeline per data source. So, I want to create one different ruleset for each data source per data quality pipeline.
Basically, I want to have one file where I define the rules for each data source and then when I execute my terraform template, it will loop over this file and apply the right set of rules for the right cloudformation execution. I don't know if I'm clear enough ?